# depedency for magento configuration in magento2

Tags: magento2, configuration

I have tried to set dependency for configuration setting of magento 2 but not able to set.
So, How can I put dependency in system.xml file in magento2 for configuration?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To create dependent object in `system.xml` following syntax will work that you have to put in field tag of yours and "id" will be field`s id on which your field is depend.

```
<depends>
    <field id="enabled">1</field>
</depends>
```

**Multiple Dependency:**

```
<field id="text" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="20" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
    <label>Your Field</label>
    <depends>
        <field id="id_of_depend_field" separator=",">1,3</field>
    </depends>
</field>
```

Comment: Thanks for you kind help. It is same as magento 1 but with small changes. I have tried to find but does not got right syntax. :)