# Magento2: Toggle button yes/no to enable/disable module function in shipment method/

Tags: custom-button, mapping, toggle

For the new shipment method, I created a **toggle button yes/no** to **enable/disable module function**. But the issue is while selecting **yes** or **no** module unable to work in that button function. please check below code and images and module code and give any clue how can I bind logic into the button.
[image]
Packt/Shipme/etc/adminhtml/system.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
    <system>
        <section id="carriers"><group id="shipme" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="50"
                                      showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
            <label>Shipme</label>
            <field id="status" type="checkbox" translate="label" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="0">

              <frontend_model>Packt\Shipme\Block\Adminhtml\System\Config\Advanced</frontend_model>
              <attribute type="shared">1</attribute>
            </field>
            <field id="name" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="20"
                   showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                <label>Method Name</label>
            </field>
            <field id="title" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="20"
                   showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                <label>Method Title</label>
            </field>
            <field id="express_enabled" translate="label" type="select"
                   sortOrder="30" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="0"><label>Enable express</label>
                <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model>
            </field>
            <field id="express_title" translate="label" type="text"
                   sortOrder="40" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                <label>Title express</label>
            </field>
            <field id="express_price" translate="label" type="text"
                   sortOrder="50" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                <label>Price express</label>
            </field>
            <field id="business_enabled" translate="label" type="select"
                   sortOrder="60" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="0">
                <label>Enable business</label>
                <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model>
            </field>
            <field id="business_title" translate="label" type="text"
                   sortOrder="70" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                <label>Title business</label>
            </field>
            <field id="business_price" translate="label" type="text"
                   sortOrder="80" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                <label>Price business</label>
            </field>
            <field id="specificerrmsg" translate="label" type="textarea"
                   sortOrder="90" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                <label>Displayed Error Message</label>
            </field>
            <field id="sallowspecific" translate="label" type="select"
                sortOrder="100" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="0">
                <label>Ship to Applicable Countries</label>
                <frontend_class>shipping-applicable-country</frontend_class>
                <source_model>Magento\Shipping\Model\Config\Source\Allspecificcountries</source_model>
            </field>
            <field id="specificcountry" translate="label" type="multiselect"
                sortOrder="110" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="0">
                    <label>Ship to Specific Countries</label>
                <source_model>Magento\Directory\Model\Config\Source\Country</source_model>
                <can_be_empty>1</can_be_empty>
            </field>
        </group>
        </section>
    </system>
</config>
```

/Packt/Shipme/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Store:etc/con
fig.xsd">
    <default>
        <carriers>
            <shipme>
                <model>Packt\Shipme\Model\Carrier\Shipme</model>
                <active>1</active>
                <name>Shipme Shipping</name>
                <title>Shipme Shipping</title>
                <express_enabled>1</express_enabled>
                <express_title>Express delivery</express_title>
                <express_price>4</express_price><business_enabled>1</business_enabled>
                <business_title>Business delivery</business_title>
                <business_price>5</business_price>
                <specificerrmsg>This shipping method is currently unavailable.
                    If you would like to ship using this shipping method, please contact
                    us.</specificerrmsg>
            </shipme>
        </carriers>
    </default>
</config>
```

/Shipme/Model/Carrier/Shipme.php

```
<?php
namespace Packt\Shipme\Model\Carrier;
use Magento\Shipping\Model\Rate\Result;
class Shipme extends \Magento\Shipping\Model\Carrier\AbstractCarrier implements
    \Magento\Shipping\Model\Carrier\CarrierInterface {
    protected $_code = 'shipme';
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Shipping\Model\Rate\ResultFactory
     */
    protected $_rateResultFactory;
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\MethodFactory
     */
    protected $_rateMethodFactory;
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
        \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\ErrorFactory
        $rateErrorFactory,
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
        \Magento\Shipping\Model\Rate\ResultFactory $rateResultFactory,
        \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\MethodFactory
        $rateMethodFactory,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_rateResultFactory = $rateResultFactory;
        $this->_rateMethodFactory = $rateMethodFactory;
        parent::__construct($scopeConfig, $rateErrorFactory, $logger,
            $data);
    }
    public function
    collectRates(\Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateRequest $request) {
        if (!$this->getConfigFlag('active')) {
            return false;
        }
        $result = $this->_rateResultFactory->create();
//Check if express method is enabled
        if ($this->getConfigData('express_enabled')) {
            $method = $this->_rateMethodFactory->create();
            $method->setCarrier($this->_code);$method->setCarrierTitle($this->getConfigData('name'));
            $method->setMethod('express');
            $method->setMethodTitle($this->getConfigData('express_title'));
            $method->setPrice($this->getConfigData('express_price'));
            $method->setCost($this->getConfigData('express_price'));
            $result->append($method);
        }
//Check if business method is enabled
        if ($this->getConfigData('business_enabled')) {
            $method = $this->_rateMethodFactory->create();
            $method->setCarrier($this->_code);
            $method->setCarrierTitle($this->getConfigData('name'));
            $method->setMethod('business');
            $method->setMethodTitle($this->getConfigData('business_title'));
            $method->setPrice($this->getConfigData('business_price'));
            $method->setCost($this->getConfigData('business_price'));
            $result->append($method);
        }
        return $result;
        }
         public function getAllowedMethods() {
            return ['shipme' => $this->getConfigData('name')];
        }
            public function isTrackingAvailable()
        {
           return true;
        }
}
```

Shipme/Block/Adminhtml/System/Config/Advanced.php

```
    <?php

    namespace Packt\Shipme\Block\Adminhtml\System\Config;

    class Advanced extends \Magento\Config\Block\System\Config\Form\Field
    {
    /**
     * Template path
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $_template = 'system/config/advance/check.phtml';

    /**
     * Render fieldset html
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\AbstractElement $element
     * @return string
     */
    public function render(\Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\AbstractElement $element)
    {
        $columns = $this->getRequest()->getParam('website') || $this->getRequest()->getParam('store') ? 5 : 4;
        return $this->_decorateRowHtml($element, "<td class='label'>Enable Shipme</td><td>" . $this->toHtml() . '</td><td></td>');
    }
    }

Shipme/view/adminhtml/templates/system/config/advance/check.phtml

<style>
.switch {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 37px;
    height: 22px;
    vertical-align: middle;

}

.switch input {
    opacity: 0;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
}

.slider {
    position: absolute;
    cursor: pointer;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: #ccc;
    -webkit-transition: .4s;
    transition: .4s;
    vertical-align: middle;

}
.sliderOne {
    position: absolute;
    cursor: pointer;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: #ccc;
    -webkit-transition: .4s;
    transition: .4s;
    vertical-align: middle;

}

.slider:before {
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    height: 22px;
    width: 22px;
    left: -7.75px;
    bottom: 0px;
    background-color: white;
    -webkit-transition: .4s;
    transition: .4s;
    vertical-align: middle;

}
.sliderOne:before {
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    height: 22px;
    width: 22px;
    left: .5px;
    bottom: 0px;
    background-color: white;
    -webkit-transition: .4s;
    transition: .4s;
    vertical-align: middle;

}

input:checked + .slider {
    background-color: #79a22e;
}

input:focus + .slider {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0px #2196F3;

}

input:checked + .sliderOne {
    background-color: #79a22e;
}

input:focus + .sliderOne {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0px #2196F3;

}

input:checked + .slider:before {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(22px);
    -ms-transform: translateX(22px);
    transform: translateX(22px);

}
input:checked + .sliderOne:before {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(22px);
    -ms-transform: translateX(22px);
    transform: translateX(22px);

}

/* Rounded sliders */
.slider.round {
    border-radius: 35px;

}

.slider.round:before {
    border-radius: 100%;
    display: inline-block;

}

.sliderOne.round {
    border-radius: 35px;

}

.sliderOne.round:before {
    border-radius: 100%;
    display: inline-block;

}

</style>
<script>
function myFunction() {

    if(document.getElementById('spa').classList.contains("slider")) {
        document.getElementsByClassName("slider")[0].setAttribute("class","sliderOne round");
        document.getElementById('toggle').innerHTML = "  &nbsp; No";
    }else{
        document.getElementsByClassName("sliderOne")[1].setAttribute("class","slider round");
        document.getElementById('toggle').innerHTML = "  &nbsp; Yes";
    }
}
</script>
<label class="switch">
    <input type="checkbox" onclick="myFunction()" checked>
    <span class="slider round" id="spa"></span>
</label>
<span id="toggle"></span>
```

Comment: i think you miss getConfigData() function

Comment: in shipme.php  have already     if (!$this->getConfigFlag('active')) {
            return false;
        }.

Comment: @irshad, Let me know if you need any help here then

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace your below files with these content

> Shipme/Block/Adminhtml/System/Config/Advanced.php

```
<?php

namespace Packt\Shipme\Block\Adminhtml\System\Config;

class Advanced extends \Magento\Config\Block\System\Config\Form\Field
{
    protected $_template = 'system/config/advance/check.phtml';

    protected $_configPath = 'carriers/shipme/status'; //replace your config path here

    protected $_groupName = 'shipme'; // replace this with your group name

    protected $_fieldName = 'status'; // replace this with your field name

    public function render(\Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\AbstractElement $element)
    {
        return $this->_decorateRowHtml($element, "<td class='label'>Enable </td><td>" . $this->toHtml() . '</td><td></td>');
    }

    public function getConfigPath(){
        return $this->_configPath;
    }

    public function getGroupName(){
        return $this->_groupName;
    }

    public function getFieldName(){
        return $this->_fieldName;
    }
}
```

> Shipme/view/adminhtml/templates/system/config/advance/check.phtml

```
<?php $configPath = $this->getConfigPath(); ?>
<?php $groupName = $this->getGroupName(); ?>
<?php $fieldName = $this->getFieldName(); ?>
<?php $inputFieldName = "groups[".$groupName."][fields][".$fieldName."][value]"; ?>
<?php $isEnabled = $this->helper('Vendor\Shipme\Helper\Data')->getConfig($configPath); ?>

<label class="switch">
    <input type="checkbox" class="enable-disable-checkbox" name="<?php echo $inputFieldName; ?>" value="<?php echo $isEnabled; ?>">
    <span class="slider round" id="enable-disable-config"></span>
</label>
<span id="toggle">
    <span class="toggle-yes"><?php echo "&nbsp;&nbsp;  Yes"; ?></span>
    <span class="toggle-no"><?php echo "&nbsp;&nbsp;  No"; ?></span>
</span>

<style>
    .switch {
        position: relative;
        display: inline-block;
        width: 37px;
        height: 22px;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }

    .switch input {
        opacity: 0;
        width: 0;
        height: 0;
    }

    .slider {
        position: absolute;
        cursor: pointer;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        background-color: #ccc;
        -webkit-transition: .4s;
        transition: .4s;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }
    .sliderOne {
        position: absolute;
        cursor: pointer;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        background-color: #ccc;
        -webkit-transition: .4s;
        transition: .4s;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }

    .slider:before {
        position: absolute;
        content: "";
        height: 22px;
        width: 22px;
        left: -7.75px;
        bottom: 0px;
        background-color: white;
        -webkit-transition: .4s;
        transition: .4s;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }
    .sliderOne:before {
        position: absolute;
        content: "";
        height: 22px;
        width: 22px;
        left: .5px;
        bottom: 0px;
        background-color: white;
        -webkit-transition: .4s;
        transition: .4s;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }

    input.checked-checkbox + .slider {
        background-color: #79a22e;
    }

    input:focus + .slider {
        box-shadow: 0 0 0px #2196F3;

    }

    input.checked-checkbox + .sliderOne {
        background-color: #79a22e;
    }

    input:focus + .sliderOne {
        box-shadow: 0 0 0px #2196F3;

    }

    input.checked-checkbox + .slider:before {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(22px);
        -ms-transform: translateX(22px);
        transform: translateX(22px);

    }
    input.checked-checkbox + .sliderOne:before {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(22px);
        -ms-transform: translateX(22px);
        transform: translateX(22px);

    }

    /* Rounded sliders */
    .slider.round {
        border-radius: 35px;
    }

    .slider.round:before {
        border-radius: 100%;
        display: inline-block;
    }

    .sliderOne.round {
        border-radius: 35px;
    }

    .sliderOne.round:before {
        border-radius: 100%;
        display: inline-block;
    }
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">  
(function  () {    
    require(["jquery"], function($) {
        $(document).ready(function($) {

            var isEnabled = "<?php echo $isEnabled; ?>";

            if(isEnabled != 0){
                $(".enable-disable-checkbox").addClass("checked-checkbox");
                $("#enable-disable-config").addClass('sliderOne');
                $(".toggle-yes").show();
                $(".toggle-no").hide();
            }else{
                $(".toggle-yes").hide();
                $(".toggle-no").show();
            }

            $(".enable-disable-checkbox").on("click", function(e){
                if($("#enable-disable-config").hasClass('sliderOne')){
                    $(".enable-disable-checkbox").removeClass("checked-checkbox");
                    $("#enable-disable-config").removeClass('sliderOne');
                    $(".toggle-yes").hide();
                    $(".toggle-no").show();
                    $(".enable-disable-checkbox").attr('value', 0);
                }else{
                    $(".enable-disable-checkbox").addClass("checked-checkbox");
                    $("#enable-disable-config").addClass('sliderOne');
                    $(".toggle-yes").show();
                    $(".toggle-no").hide();
                    $(".enable-disable-checkbox").attr('value', 1);
                }
            });
        }); 
    });
})();
</script>
```

Create one Helper file here in your module

> Shipme/Helper/Data.php

Content for this file is..

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Shipme\Helper;

use Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context;
use Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper;

class Data extends AbstractHelper
{
    protected $_scopeConfig;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
    ) {
        $this->_scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
    }

    public function getConfig($configPath)
    {
        return $this->_scopeConfig->getValue(
            $configPath,
            \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE
        );
    }
}
```

Or you can follow this module : [Download module](https://github.com/KishanSavaliya/magehelper-magento2-enable-disable-toggle-in-configuration)

Hope this will help you!

Comment: Kishan Savaliya@: thanks, your module working  for toggle yes/no slide .. but  while slide **yes**  or **no**   module enable/disable do not work. for frontend.

Comment: @irshad, What you mean by enable/disable ? Can you please explain me that ?

Comment: So I can check what is missing there ?

Comment: while select **yes**  module  function does not enable for frontend and while  select **no**  module function does not disable for frontend.

Comment: You follow this to check enable/disable in frontend Right ?

https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/296553/magento2-function-of-enable-disable-yes-no-button-for-any-module?answertab=votes#tab-top

Comment: yes followed same line of  code

Comment: Okay then change **'active'** with **'status'** and check.

Comment: Great..!! @irshad. Can you please upvote for my answer ?

Comment: upvoted @kishan

Comment: @irshad, **and want to know is there any keyword active mechanism in Magento2 to identify word active only to enable** I didn't got this. What you're asking here?

Comment: guys, can you please find the solution of this  https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/297276/magento-2-shipping-address-payment-method-order-review-in-single-page-of-th